# Improving the speed of writing code in C#

Tags: c#, development-process

Laugh if you want, but I used to develop substantial line-of-business applications in VB6, long before the .NET framework came along.  Why, when I was your age, we used to walk two miles in the snow, uphill.  Both ways...

Love it or hate it, VB6 had a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)-like feel, and a very rapid development cycle.  I would like to know how to come closer to that process in C#.  In VB6, I could write a function, execute it, debug it and have it fully functional in a few minutes.  I am told this is how the Lisp crowd works.  It's a very rapid-fire style of programming.

In C# I write a function, then I write a unit test for that function (which is OK, I understand the value of that), then I right-click, run test, wait for the project to compile (takes about 10 seconds right now, which would be an eternity for a REPL loop), and get an exception.  Honestly, this feels more like my junior college days, when I used to feed punch cards into a hopper and wait for a printout (exaggerating only slightly for effect).

Additionally, my tendency nowadays is to make everything `public` while I'm testing it.  Unit testing with private accessors works fine, but you can't trace through the code (unless, of course, I'm doing something wrong) while you're using them.

So what I'd like to know is, what adjustments have you made to your development process in C# to streamline it, and make it possible to write and verify your code very rapidly?

Comment: Have you set Visual Studio to build the projects incrementally? That can come close to eliminating the compiling step and allow you to run your code almost as fast as you write it.

Comment: @Michael: Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483(v=VS.90).aspx) what you are referring to?  Sheesh, you'd think they would have just provided a checkbox in project properties for incremental building.

Comment: @Robert I'm sorry, it looks like I was wrong. VS [apparently doesn't have a incremental "build on save"](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/01/17/visual-studio-tip-kill-that-build.aspx#9554). I remapped my Ctrl-S to build.

Comment: @Michael: Eh, background compilation for C# was introduced in VS2008 SP1.  It's the default in VS2010.

Comment: @Aaronaught: How do you turn it on? (I have VS2008 SP1)  Actually, I think the background compilation referred to there is on-the-fly code checking in the editor.  If you want to spin up an execution, a full-blown compile is still triggered.

Comment: @Robert: Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced->Show live semantic errors.  I think it's just background *compilation*, not background *build*, but you surely architect your code so that changes to core assemblies are infrequent, right? ;)

Comment: @Aaronaught: The code base currently has about 300 files in it, and consists of an executable and one DLL. Perhaps it's time to break it out into additional DLL's.

Comment: VS2010 also seems to do a better job of background compilation; it's hard to pinpoint exactly what's going on but I've seen changes to one in-project assembly automatically get reflected in the code editor for a source file in a dependent assembly, without doing a full build - although, when I actually *do* perform a build, it has to build the entire dependency tree. It's doing some weird tricks that I don't remember seeing in VS2008.

Comment: Scheiße, that is one huge project.  These days I think a typical assembly of mine has 5-20 types (one per file).  Multiple assemblies will *increase* the overall build time from scratch, but if you're only working on a "leaf" level assembly then it won't rebuild any of the dependencies if they haven't changed, so it usually ends up being faster.  Mainly I started doing that when I started getting more serious about tests; hard to imagine writing tests for a 300-unit assembly.

Comment: @Aaronaught That would explain it; I worked with VS2005 two years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) now has three different modes for C#:

1. C# Expression (the original)
2. C# Statement(s)
3. C# Program

Although it's not a "real" REPL environment, it comes very close, and I personally have never had to tackle a problem that's too complicated for Linqpad but not complicated enough to justify proper design and unit testing.  In the "program" mode you can declare types, and in all modes you can add external namespace and assembly references.

Over time I've simply adopted this as the default method of spitballing ideas, making sure that code does what I think it does (as opposed to doing what it is *supposed* to do, which is the domain of automated tests).

If that doesn't work for you, the Mono project has [CSharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).  You need to actually install Mono, and there are a few vagaries to deal with, but [people have done it](http://lexicalclosures.blogspot.com/2010/04/mono-c-repl-on-windows.html).

(P.S. You do not need to make types or members public in order to unit test them.  A better solution, which doesn't require you to remember to "fix it later", is to make them `internal` and use the [`assembly:InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute with the name of your unit test assembly.  Visual Studio is aware of this attribute so you'll get full Intellisense and all.  And you can definitely trace execution.)

Comment: I've been looking at Linqpad for awhile (from afar, haven't actually played around with it yet). Albahari is a genius; I love his [threading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). Looks like I'm going to have to bite the bullet and purchase the Intellisense for Linqpad. Thanks for sharing your experience as someone who actually uses it in a production environment.

Comment: @Robert: I'd try out the free version first (if you haven't already) before springing for the Intellisense. I actually get by without intellisense in Linqpad, but that's probably just me being a cheapskate.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a fair comparison to compare VB without unit tests to C# with unit tests. If you want quick turnaround dont write unit tests. Personally I think they're overrated, esp for business problems.

The other option you might want to consider is having a CI server running tests there, so they aren't in you dev loop.

Finally I like making variables public too. Especially if the alternative is just to write boilerplate get/set functions. A good thing about C# is that you can change later without affecting code that uses the property.

Comment: +1 for the paragraphs on unit tests (from reconsidering the need to moving them to CI); I don't agree however with making variables public, because it's not true that promoting fields to properties won't affect other code. Just use automatic properties.

Comment: This is all around pretty terrible advice.  "Don't test business problems" -- those are exactly the ones you want to test.  They're easy and important.  "Keep tests out of the dev loop" -- CI is a final gatekeeper for broken code.  Why check it in broken?  "Use public fields instead of properties" -- until you need a property and all things compiled against your library need recompilation.  That's what auto properties are for.